# Method name for getter which never returns null?

Tags: google-apps-script, coding-style

I'm working on simple implementation for storage controller in Google Apps Script, which responsibility is to connect to spreadsheet file and create, read and update rows and sheets. In constructor I want to initialize "configuration sheet" member and I want to do it with method like: getConfgurationSheet(). This is the next time when I'm not sure if the "get" is a good prefix for a method, which will return already existing instance of entity or create a new one.

My idea is to use 'find' instead of 'get' when it's possible to return null, like not finding anything, and 'get' when I'm sure my method will provide not null object.

What are your suggestions about this?

Answer (score 0):

When I return a "fixed" resource like this, I usually just write the resource name directly, without a verb, e.g. `configSheet()`.

I also normally cache it in the library (lazily on 1st access) so that the client script can just call it whenever need, multiple times without worrying with performance impacts (like getting the sheet every time, or getting it unnecessarily).

```js
var c_ = {}; //library lazy object holder

function ss() { return c_.ss || (c_.ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FIXED_ID)); }

function configSheet() { return c_.config || (c_.config = ss().getSheetByName(CONFIG_SHEET); }
```

Comment: its similar to 'property' convention but still it sounds like its responsibillity is to act as a gateway to some other object. I was thinking of name for more responsible action - creation of new data if its missing. "configSheet()" doesn't tell me it will create new sheet if necessary.

Comment: I'm not an expert on libraries, but for me a library goal is always to make my life easier and hide implementation details from me. I think a good place to inform that it even creates the resource if it's missing is the documentation.  A verb-less method indicates to me that there's minimal penalty in calling it, usually the resource is already there. Also, I normally don't care how it's done, and if I do, I'd read the method documentation... my two cents.